# Array is splitted into multiple arrays in console after api request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firefox, ecmascript-6

I want to log the output/data of an api request in json, but the array is splittin into multiple ones

Console:

```
[0...99]
[100...199]
[200...299]
[300...399]
```

Expected: normal array with some items

Actual: array is splitted in multiple arrays

Comment: It's not split into multiple arrays. It's just how the console chooses to display an array with a lot of elements.

Comment: well, is there any way to change it. I had Safari before and I liked that way more

Comment: Each of those groups will expand when clicked in console

Comment: This is not a programming question...

Comment: @MattChampion What's it that you need? Why is it a problem? You can still inspect all the elements by expanding and checking. If you really insist one way is to copy the value and paste it into an editor, would that work for you? If yes, I shall detail out the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array has not been split up - that's your console. You can see the indexes are all correspondent to the same array, and you can access all of them just like you normally would. If you loop through the array, you can still access all items as per normal.